# jQuery.each() target element with ajax, always targets the last item in the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `unordered list`, and I am looping through each `li` child of the `ul`:

```
<ul>
<li value="1">Item 1</li>
<li value="2">Item 2</li>
<li value="3">Item 3</li>
<li value="4">Item 4</li>
<li value="5">Item 5</li>
<ul>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("ul").children("li").each(function(idx, el){
            e = $(el); // Assign the element

             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/_ajax/_myService.svc/getRandomNumber",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {                    
                e.text(e.text() + " (" + msg.d + ")")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the AJAX function returns a random number (for now) and appends it to the end of the `li` text in brackets.

If I set the ajax call to `async: false` it works, however that is not recommended due to freezing the browser etc. If I leave it defaulted to `true` then all the items are appended to the last item in the loop, so I end up with:

```
<ul>
<li value="1">Item 1</li>
<li value="2">Item 2</li>
<li value="3">Item 3</li>
<li value="4">Item 4</li>
<li value="5")Item 5 (12) (234) (1334) (14) (34)</li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the ajax call to maintain it's target reference it's been called with? I've tried placing the call into a separate function, however I get the same result!

Comment: You shouldnt use AJAX in loops, If multiple AJAX calls are required then use `.then` and `.when` jQuery API

Comment: @vinayaki I'm manipulating the element of the loop as well. I'll take a look at `.then`, many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
 e = $(el); // Assign the element
```

to

```
var  e = $(el); // Assign the element
```

Comment: *slaps forehead* obvious now! Thank you